# Why can't I insert a blank line in this code?

Tags: macros, best-practices

In the code below, everything is OK until I insert a blank line instead of one of the `\\`'s. Upon inserting a blank line, I'll get some errors. How can I get rid of these errors?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand{\Class}[1]
{ 
\sbox{\mybox}{\begin{tabular}{l}#1\end{tabular}}
\fbox{\parbox{\wd\mybox}{\texttt{#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
\Class
{double Width\\
 double Height\\
 double Perimeter\\ 
 double Area\\
}

\usebox\mybox
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
My indented output is:
[image]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Any solutions which do the trick is appreciated.

Comment: What do you intend this code to do, it s very weird, why are you setting `#`` twice in both a tabular and a parbox? Surely it makes more sense just to put the `\fbox` around the tabular?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see my update. I added a screenshot.

Comment: "indented" or "intended"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\texttt` does not allow paragraph breaks in its argument. You could use `\ttfamily` instead but a blank line inside a tabular doesn't do anything useful, so it is probably better to have the error message to warn of the incorrect input.

Perhaps this which makes a blank line do `\\` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mybox
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\Class}[1]
{%
\sbox{\mybox}{\begin{tabular}{>{\expandafter\def\csname par\endcsname{\\}}l}#1\end{tabular}}%
\fbox{\parbox{\wd\mybox}{\par{\def\par{\\}\ttfamily{#1}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\Class
{double Width\\
 double Height

 double Perimeter\\ 
 double Area\\
}

\usebox\mybox
\end{document}
```

Comment: So could you please provide me with another solution instead of the `tabular` environment which give me the same output?

Comment: I could if I could guess what you want a blank line to do? As I say if you change \texttt to \ttfamily it works without error but perhaps isn't the output you want

Comment: As for the output, You are completely right. If I change `\texttt` to `\ttfamily`, it works without errors, but the width of the frame, becomes bigger.

Comment: @DavaidCarlisle your solution works, but could you please tell me why after inserting `\Class
{double Width\ double Height ‎bla‎ ‎bla‎‎ ‎bla‎‎   

 double Perimeter  ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\\ 
 double Area\}`, the third bla falls in the next line in spite of the enough space?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply `\fbox` the `tabular` and use `\\` for blank lines; to get typewriter type use `\ttfamily`; the `\fbox` keeps the font change local.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Class}[1]{%
  \fbox{\ttfamily\begin{tabular}{l}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}
\Class
{double Width\\
 double Height\\
 \\
 double Perimeter\\
 double Area\\
}

\end{document}
```

Beware of spurious spaces and comment end of lines in definitions.

[image]